# How to convert ReadableInstant (Joda Time) to Java Date?

Tags: date, jodatime

How does one convert a ReadableInstant (in Joda Time) to a java.util.Date ? ReadableInstant doesn't seem to have any methods that allow one to convert to a Date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is a bit simpler than I thought. ReadableInstant does provide a getMillis() function that returns the epoch time as a Long, so we can use that to convert to a Date.

```
ReadableInstant instant;
Date date = new Date(instant.getMillis());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like this.

```
ReadableInstant instant;
Date date = DateTime.toDateTime(instant.getChronology()).toDate();
```

But performance wise not so good